# Finding functions with the given properties

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

In the following questions I am trying to find a function with the given properties or explain why no such function exists.

1) An infinitely differentiable function on $R$ with the Taylor series that only converges on $(-1,1)$

For this I have chosen the geometric series,

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$

So this series is a geometric series and only converges when $|r|<1$. Thus, converges only for $(-1,1)$ but is this series infinitely differentiable?

2) An inifinitely differentiable function on $R$ with a Taylor Series that only converges for $x\le0$

Would the following series work? $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^{n}}{n}$$

Comment: Have you calculated the radius of convergence?  $a_n=\frac{(-x)^n}{n}$ so $$|a_n|^{1/n}=\dots=x$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter could you suggest a function that works?

Comment: I dunno.  Let's wait for an ans.

Comment: @GNUSupporter does number 1 not work either? thanks for your edit

Comment: The answer speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. That function fails to be differentiable at $x = 1$. But you're on the right track. The radius of convergence of the power series is always less than the distance to the nearest singularity. But to be differentiable on $\mathbb R$, it can't have any singularities for $x \in \mathbb R$. How do we reconcile this?
2. No. Aside from the fact that, as written, the first term is 1/0, if we start from $n=1$ that is the series for $-\ln|1+x|$, which converges for $|x|<1$ and is not everywhere differentiable. The answer to this question depends on whether we require the power series to be about 0 and whether we need it to converge for all $x \le 0$ or just for no values $x > 0$. It's  also worth noting that there exist infinitely differentiable functions with a convergent power series at $x = 0$, but that series only converges *to the value of the function* for $ x  \le 0$.

Comment: so number 1 and 2 are incorrect? I thought number 1 would be convergent for $x\in (-1,1)$ for number 1 when you say it fails to be differentiable at x=1 is that because the denominator would be 0?

Comment: Yes. The function is infinitely differentiable on $(-1,1)$, but it is not differentiable on $\mathbb R$ due to the singularity at $x = 1$.

Comment: could you suggest a function that works?

Comment: $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ is such a function. The key is that its singularities $x$ have $|x| = 1$, but $x \notin \mathbb R$.

Comment: okay so from your last comment, An infinitely differentiable function on $R$ with the Taylor series that only converges on $(-1,1)$ would be $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x^2)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2k},$$

Comment: Yes. Hopefully it's clear that that series diverges for $|x| \ge 1$.

Comment: yes I can see how that diverges for those values of x. Could you suggest a function for number 2? and I will try and get the taylor series formula for it

Comment: I would need to know more about what is desired of the function. Must the series be about 0? Must the series converge for all $x \le 0$? Must the series be convergent, or are we also requiring the series to converge to the value of the function at that point.

Comment: yes it only converges for all x<=0, and I don't think it needs to be about 0 but that would be good too if it was possible, and no it does not require the series to converge to the value of the function at the point

Comment: Such a power series is not possible. It would need to have infinite radius of convergence to converge for all $x \le 0$, but that would mean it converges for all $x$.

Comment: okay thanks, I guess that's why I was having trouble finding such series. But would it be possible to find a infinitely differentiable function on $R$ with a taylor series that only converge to $f(x)$ for x<=0?

Comment: Yes. $f(x) = u(x)\exp(-1/x)$, where $u(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. Its power series about 0 is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0x^n$, which clearly converges to 0 for all $x$, but to the value of the function only for $x \le 0$. This function is continuously differentiable to all orders.

Comment: okay so $f(x)=u(x)^{\frac{-1}{x}}$,is there a particular Heaviside step function $u(x)$?

Comment: would $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto\cases{0\qquad\textrm{if }x\le0\cr\exp\left(-\frac1x\right)\quad\textrm{otherwise}}$$ work?

Comment: Yes. That is, in fact, the function I said. The Heaviside step function is 1 for positive x and 0 for nonpositive x.

Comment: okay thanks, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}0x^n$ works perfectly then